# How to do math operations in android shell?

Tags: shell, calculator

To do math operations in Linux shell, bc language can be used. For example,

```
echo `echo "scale=4;sqrt(400)"|bc -l`
```

This will give output of 20.0000

Unfortunately bc is not available on android. My question is,

1) How do I do math operations in android shell?

2) If bc has to be used, then, how to install it in android?

It is good enough for me if I can do integer calculations, I don't really need floating point or arbitrary precision results.

Comment: One way to do the very basic arithmetic operations is the following: `echo $((2+2))`, here + can be replaced by *,-,\ and all of these work fine. But I don't know how to perform square root.

Answer (score 1):

BusyBox doesn't include `bc`, but it does include the Reverse Polish Notation calculator `dc`.  Since Busybox can be installed from several installers on Google Play, this is probably the easiest way to get a command-line-based calculator on Android.

Alternatively, I've heard that `bc` can be compiled for Android quite easily using the Android NDK, so if you're comfortable with compiling software you could do this.